# make the html5 video return to the first frame (native javascript )

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following function make the html5 video return to the first frame instead of stay at the last frame after finishing the video
could you please help me to convert this method to native javascript code !

```
 $("#brandvoice-promo-video_html5_api").on("ended", function()
        {
           this.currentTime =0;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("brandvoice-promo-video_html5_api");
elem.addEventListener("ended", function() {elem.currentTime = 0;});
```

Comment: getElementById insted of getElementByID